# ¿Qué contiene un JLabel vacío?

Tags: java, string, java-swing

Mi idea es setear en un `JLabel` el número de ventas que se van dando en un mes y se reinicia en 1 al comenzar el día del mes siguiente.

Suponiendo que un `JLabel` posee `""` como contenido, ya que estuve buscando y no encontré nada al respecto, realicé el siguiente algoritmo.

```
//JlabelMov 
   SimpleDateFormat sds = new SimpleDateFormat("dd"); 
   String dia = sds.format(fecha);
   if( !"01".equals(dia) && !LabelMov.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
       mov = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(LabelMov.getText())+ 1);
       LabelMov.setText(mov);
   }
   else{
      //mov = String.valueOf(1);
      LabelMov.setText(mov);
   }
```

El problema es que cada movimiento que realizó mi `JLabel` siempre queda seteado en 1, pensando que `LabelMov.getText();` no devuelve `""` si no tiene nada.

Codigo faltante:

```
      package elbuengusto;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Locale;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
    import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JSpinner;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
    import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
    import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

    /**
     *
     * @author jorge
     */
public class NuevaVenta extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   DefaultTableModel mt4;
   Date fecha = new Date();//fecha y hora actual
   int etiq = fecha.getDate();
   String mov = String.valueOf(1);

public NuevaVenta() {
    initComponents();
   //JLabelFechaSeteada

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //formatear la fecha en una cadena
    FechaAc.setText(sdf.format(fecha)); //setear la representacion en cadena de la fech

   //JlabelMov 
   SimpleDateFormat sds = new SimpleDateFormat("dd"); 
   String dia = sds.format(fecha);
   if( !"01".equals(dia) && !LabelMov.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
       mov = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(LabelMov.getText())+ 1);
       LabelMov.setText(mov);
   }
   else{
      //mov = String.valueOf(1);
      LabelMov.setText(mov);
   }

     //tabVentas

     String titulos4 [] = {"Descripcion","Cant" };// creando la tabla a gusto
     String filas4 [][] = {};

     mt4 = new DefaultTableModel(filas4, titulos4);

     TableColumnModel colVentas = TabVentas.getColumnModel(); //para poder modificar los anchos de las columnas

     TabVentas.setModel(mt4);// para poder mostrar la tabla
     //para que te tome la modificacion del tamanio tenes que hacerlo despues de mostrar la tabla
     colVentas.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(55);
     colVentas.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(300);

}`
```

Comment: ¿Qué tal si intentas con `LabelMov.getText().trim()`?

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y no hay cambio en la ejecucion

Comment: yo no se pero si usted esta usando Date, pero si es asi son Deprecated: puede mirar esto http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.getDay%28%29 igual getDay no funciona como usted cree, aqui puede ver sobre lo que comenta sobre la variable text http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JLabel.java#117 tambien puede mirar getData y ver su alter. si es lo que quiere y busca http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.getDate%28%29

Comment: @Angel Angel Gracias! le voy a pegar una leída!

Answer (score 1):

El valor de una instancia de `JLabel` cuyo texto no se ha indicado es una cadena vacía `""`. Esto se puede ver en [las fuentes de `JLabel`, línea 119](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/JLabel.java). Tu evaluación de cadenas de texto es correcta y debe funcionar.

Tu problema está en el uso de [`Date#getDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay--). Según la documentación de dicho método:

> Returns the day of the week represented by this date. The returned value (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, 4 = Thursday, 5 = Friday, 6 = Saturday) represents the day of the week that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this `Date` object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

En español:

> Devuelve el día de la semana representado por esta fecha. El valor retornado (0 = Domingo, 1 = Lunes, 2 = Martes, 3 = Miércoles, 4 = Jueves, 5 = Viernes, 6 = Sábado) representa el día de la semana que contiene o que empieza con el instante de tiempo representado por este objeto `Date`, como se interpreta en la zona de tiempo local.

Es decir, que devolverá 1 si el día que evalúas es Lunes. Dado que lo que necesitas es evaluar si es el primer día del mes, lo que puedes hacer es obtener el número de día del mes de la fecha y evaluar dicha fecha. Aquí unos ejemplos de cómo realizarlo:

Ejemplo 1, utilizando `Calendar`:

```
public boolean esPrimeroDeMes(Date fecha) {
    Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendario.setTime(fecha);
    return calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 1;
}
```

Ejemplo 2, utilizando `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
//escrito de manera extendida, se puede reducir a 1 sola línea de código
public boolean esPrimeroDeMes(Date fecha) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    String dia = sdf.format(fecha);
    return "01".equals(dia);
}
```

Ejemplo 3, si utilizas Java 8, puedes hacer uso de la nueva API de fecha y hora:

```
public boolean esPrimeroDeMes(Date fecha) {
    LocalDate fechaLocal = fecha.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    return fechaLocal.getDayOfMonth() == 1;
}
```

Comment: Gracias @Luiggi Mendoza, lo eh corregido pero me sigue pasando lo mismo, lo raro es que setea el "1" pero al ingresar un nuevo movimiento mi jLabel sigue vació. Lo confirme con un breackpoint.

Comment: Me pregunto si estás revisando el JLabel correcto

Comment: si, estoy revisando el JLabel correcto, el `LabelMov` .

Comment: Entonces por favor publica más código para replicar tu problema

Comment: El código ya esta publicado.

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez la verdad que no entiendo bien tu problema. Tu lógica en el código dice: `si no es el primer día del mes y el JLabel no está vacío, entonces ponle un texto, de lo contrario (es decir, si es primer día del mes y está vacío) ponle un texto`. ¿Es eso lo que quieres como condiciones para colocar un texto en tu `JLabel`?

Comment: Claro, ya que si no es el 1er dia y el JLabel no esta vacio, le sumo +1 a lo que tenga el JLabel para ir sumando el num de movimientos que halla a lo largo del mes. De lo contrario si es el dia 1 del mes o el JLabel esta vacio, osea sin movimientos, debo empezar con un num. de movimiento igual a 1. `String mov = String.valueOf(1);`

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez no sería mejor solo usar el `if` para validar si debes actualizar el valor de `mov` y luego, sin importar la fecha ni el valor del texto, actualizar directamente el valor de tu `JLabel`?

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza y pero para validarlo tengo que saber la fecha y si el JLabel esta vacio o lo que contenga, para poder ir sumandole +1.  Ademas de volver el contador a 1 al iniciar el mes...

Comment: @JorgeGonzalez [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37601/discussion-between-luiggi-mendoza-and-jorge-gonzalez).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizar la validación mediante:

```
label.getText().isEmpty()
```

Ejemplo:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
if (label.getText().isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("ESTA VACIO!");
}else{
    System.out.println("NO ESTA VACIO!");
}
```

Lo mismo para :

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(); 
label.setText("");
if (label.getText().isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("ESTA VACIO!");
} else {
    System.out.println("NO ESTA VACIO!");
}
```

En ambos casos indicará que el `JLabel`, `"ESTA VACIO!"`.

Puedes hacer uso también del método [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()), el cual ayuda a omitir los espacios vacíos.

```
label.setText("    ");        
label.getText().trim().isEmpty();
```

Que sería la solución a tu problema...

*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

```
   String etiq = LabelMov.getText();
   if(fecha.getDay() != 1 && !LabelMov.getText().trim().isEmpty())
       etiq = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(etiq)+ 1);
       LabelMov.setText(etiq);       
   else
      etiq = String.valueOf(1);
      LabelMov.setText(etiq);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Elenasys, lo eh implementado pero haciendo un breack point me di cuenta que en cada venta realizada, el JLabel sigue teniendo `" "`.                                                                                  `if(fecha.getDay() != 1 && !etiq.isEmpty())`

Comment: Entonces usa: if(fecha.getDay() != 1 && !LabelMov.getText().trim().isEmpty()) { ...

Comment: Sin cambios....

Comment: Entonces ahora el problema es otro, que valor obtienes de fecha.getDay() ?

Comment: `fecha.getDay()` me devuelve el valor 4, que segun lei representa el dia jueves.

Comment: Pero ademas cuando yo hago `LabelMov.setText(String.valueOf(1))` no se guarda el valor "1" que paso como argumento, la 2da venta sigue apareciendo true, que esta vacio.

Comment: Es que debes cambiar el valor en la variable etiq. etiq = String.valueOf(1); LabelMov.setText(etiq);

Comment: `boolean mov = LabelMov.getText().trim().isEmpty();
       String etiq = String.valueOf(1);
       if(fecha.getDay() != 1 && !mov){
                         LabelMov.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(LabelMov.getText())+ 1));
       }
       else
          LabelMov.setText(etiq);`

Comment: No cambio en nada, en la 2da venta tendria que aparecer el valor seteado por 1ra vez en el `setText(etiq)` del `else` . Pero no lo guarda

Comment: Revisa el bloque de código que agregué, en el if lo que validas es si el día es diferente de 1 y si el JLabel no tiene texto (esta vacío), si se cumple esto cambias el valor de la variable etiq y ese mismo valor lo agregar al JLabel. En otro caso únicamente agregas "1" al JLabel, esto es lo que deseas?

Comment: lo acabo de implementar, el valor no cambia.